# How to create offline database for Phonegap mobile application?

Tags: json, cordova, phonegap-build

I am creating phonegap mobile app for Android and I need to store questions in offline mode with app. Can I use JSON for this. If yes please guide me how can I store my questions in separate text file and how can I access the specific question in my app from the container text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use localStorage to store your questions as an array of objects as follows:

```
questions = [
   { id : 1, text: "Question 1 text goes here" },
   { id : 2, text: "Question 2 text goes here" },
   { id : 3, text: "Question 3 text goes here" },
   { id : 4, text: "Question 4 text goes here" }
];

window.localStorage.setItem("questions" , JSON.stringify(questions));
```

And then to read it back you use JSON.parse();

```
questions = JSON.parse( window.localStorage.getItem("questions"));
console.log(questions);
```

P.S. data stored in localStorage doesn't expire and stays after your phonegap application is closed.

Comment: Localstorage allows only 5MB of data. For large size data SQLite database or HTML5 based WebSql database(max db size can be 50MB) should be use.

Comment: Good point, localStorage is good choice as long as the questions are not expected to grow over 5mb.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use android sqlite, you can find phonegap/cordova plugins for that.
Sqlite is a lightweight RDBMS.

Let me know if you are facing any issues setting it up.

Abhijeet Naik
www.pattypets.com

Comment: To use it, will I have to install any other software like sql?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebSql database. It doesn't require any additional plugin to install with Phonegap app. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

WebSql database have database size limit of 50MB. So if you want to go with higher storage capacity, you can choose Sqlite database. To use Sqlite databse in Phonegap app, you need Sqlite plugin. https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage